# Best Hashing Algorithm to mine in 2017? SHA? Scrypt?

Tags: mining-hardware

I have always been interested in mining cryptocurrency and I am wondering what the best hashing algorithm to mine is? I've looked at the list of the most popular crypto currencies and it seems they all use different hashing algorithms. I know I'm a few years late in the game and bitcoins will all be mined out soon. I think I might be able to jump in. I don't assume it's possible to have a miner that can mine multiple hashing algorithms but if that is, please tell me! Basically I'm looking into buying a miner but I don't know which hashing algorithms is still viable in 2017. Thanks so much for any answers!

-Todd

Comment: "I just found out that I don't pay electricity" – You mean, you either pay indirectly for it or it's subsidized by your neighbors? ;)

Comment: I pay for it it my rent but because they don't have meters on the individual apartments, you can use as much electronics as you want

Comment: Yes, that's what I've said: you're privatizing profits but socializing costs.

Comment: wow, who knew that such a bad question could get so many views. Thanks internet.

Comment: When your landlord sees his electric bill go out of sight your rent will go up. Nothing is free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below table, you can check how profitable it is to mine XY coin:

https://whattomine.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The market prices change daily, so posting the answer here is useless.

Comment: That's probably true, but that's because it's not a good question to begin with. Answers on Stack Exchange should not depend solely on external content, links should only be for *additional information*. I don't think you're affiliated with this site, but this answer conforms to patterns used by spammers to promote their websites.

Comment: @Böhmermann, an answer on this site should be valid even if it is years old and the references linked in the answer are long defunct.  This answer doesn't fit that description.  It's a bad question to begin with, but that doesn't mean we should be providing bad answers as well.  In this case, you should explain the factors that go into mining profitability rather than simply providing a link that calculates for you.